# Implement a method to set some TextView properties

Tags: java, android

I need to implement a custom method to switch some `TextView` background colors according to the position of the seekbar (except the first and last position , they are fixed).

I need to do it to 10 views. So I made this class `SwitchColor` to try to automate my work. The constructor uses 4 parameters: the `TextView` I want to change the background, the seekbar position, the initial color, and the final color.

I'm not sure how to call the internal method `SwitchTextViewBackground()` from the new object `SwitchColor`.

My MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private static SeekBar seekbar;
private static TextView textview;

private static TextView topSqr;
private static TextView middleSqr;
private static TextView middleSqrContentA;
private static TextView MiddleSqrContentB;
private static TextView bottomSqr;
private static TextView stripe1;
private static TextView stripe2;
private static TextView stripe3;
private static TextView stripe4;
private static TextView stripe5;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    seekBarAction();
}


private void seekBarAction() {

    seekbar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBar);
    seekbar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(
            new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
                int seekBarProgressValue = 0;

                SwitchColor switchColor = new SwitchColor(topSqr,seekBarProgressValue,"#FFF","#000");
                switchColor.SwitchTextViewBackground(); // cannot resolve Symbol

                @Override
                public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int i, boolean b) {
                seekBarProgressValue = i;
                }

                @Override
                public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

                }

            }
    );

}}
```

And my custom class:

```
public class SwitchColor{
private TextView view;
private int colorIndex;
private String initialColor;
private String finalColor;

public SwitchColor(TextView view, int colorIndex, String initialColor, String finalColor) {
    this.view = view;
    this.colorIndex = colorIndex;
    this.initialColor = initialColor;
    this.finalColor = finalColor;
}

public void SwitchTextViewBackground(){

    if(colorIndex <= 10 && colorIndex < 0) {
        view.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(initialColor));
    } else {
        if (colorIndex <= 90 && colorIndex <=100){
            view.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(finalColor));
        }
        else {
            Random rnd = new Random();
            int color = Color.argb(rnd.nextInt(256), rnd.nextInt(256), rnd.nextInt(256), rnd.nextInt(256));
            view.setBackgroundColor(color);
        }
    }
}}
```

Comment: did you post any screenShot??

Comment: `static` views in Android? Ughhhh.

Comment: What EpicPandaForce is trying to say is that the `static` keyword is very unnecessary in this scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit your SwithchColor class like this

```
public class SwitchColor{
    private TextView view;
    private int colorIndex;
    private String initialColor;
    private String finalColor;

    public SwitchColor(TextView view, int colorIndex, String initialColor,   String finalColor) {
        this.view = view;
        this.colorIndex = colorIndex;
        this.initialColor = initialColor;
        this.finalColor = finalColor;
        SwitchTextViewBackground();//Change is here
    }

    public void SwitchTextViewBackground(){

        if(colorIndex <= 10 && colorIndex < 0) {
            view.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(initialColor));
        } else {
            //if (colorIndex <= 90 && colorIndex <=100){ 
            if (colorIndex >= 90 && colorIndex <=100){//Here is an edit
                view.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(finalColor));
            }
            else {
                Random rnd = new Random();
                int color = Color.argb(rnd.nextInt(256), rnd.nextInt(256),     rnd.nextInt(256), rnd.nextInt(256));
                view.setBackgroundColor(color);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then Edit inside seekBarAction like this

```
private void seekBarAction() {

    seekbar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBar);
    seekbar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(
            new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
                //int seekBarProgressValue = 0;

                //SwitchColor switchColor = new SwitchColor(topSqr,seekBarProgressValue,"#FFF","#000");
               // switchColor.SwitchTextViewBackground(); // cannot resolve Symbol

                @Override
                public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int i, boolean b) {
                //seekBarProgressValue = i;
                //Edit is here 
                SwitchColor switchColor = new SwitchColor(topSqr,i,"#FFFFFF","#000000");
                }

                @Override
                public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

                }

            }
    );

}}
```